# Connecting Proximity beacon with Mobile App

Tags: protocols, beacons, eddystone

We are planning to implement a proximity beacon network which provides information to the users app based on proximity in the store. Our objective is to cover a radius of 5-7 metres.

Which protocol has the better connectivity between the beacon and the iOS/Android app?

The Network will be as below,

[image: process flow of customer using a beacon]

To clarify, we are focusing on Eddystone over the other protocols because of Google. Considering the current situation in beacon technology, is there a better alternative for communication with mobile applications? If there are any, what is the advantage over Eddystone?

Comment: Please include at least a few protocols you consider already. I small bit of research is required for all SE questions.

Comment: Just to be clear - your user devices will only be smartphones?

Comment: Smartphones/Tablets.

Comment: you can go with estimote beacons, Estimote beacons providing iOS SDK for both proximity and location beacons. Estimote added many filter methods to provide high efficient communication between ios app and beacons. For android we proximity beacon SDK available butUnfortunately we don't have android SDK for location beacon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is currently a better option out there. It doesn't even need an app to work since it can provide URLs, it's open-source and more secure than the main competitors due to ephemeral IDs and they provide telemetry.

[This blog](https://blog.beaconstac.com/2016/06/googles-eddystone-vs-apples-ibeacon-who-is-winning-in-the-beacon-space-in-2016/) lists a lot of reasons why the Eddystone beacons have risen so much in popularity. Between the lines one can even presume that they consider iBeacon dead barring some fundamentally changed successor.

The Eddystone beacons just bring more ecosystem, accessibility and flexibility out of the box. So in December 2016, Eddystone seems to be the only sensible protocol choice. (Unless you intend to equip an Apple campus ;))

A lot of blog entries I found moved over the year from *"let's compare the protocols"*, over *"oh, Apple didn't even mention theirs in their keynote"* to *"the reasons why Eddystone won."*